# Unable to action controller method through ajax

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I'm currently trying to send data back to a controller for the controller to than pass to a model.

When I hit the submit button (with all fields filled in) I get a success response which fires the confirmation dropdown but the     brand/save_new_brand() method doesn't fire. I have     print_r($_POST); die(); just to be sure but still nothing.

The path in the request is correct and is the same barring the method call as the redirect on success so it should be fine there.

Here's what I have...

```
            $.ajax({
            url: "<?=sbase_url()?>admin/brands/save_new_brand",
            global: true,
            type: "POST",
            data: ({
                <?php 
                    foreach($languages as $lang): 
                        if($lang['language_status'] == 'SHOW'):
                            echo "'brand_name_" . $lang['language_id'] . "' : $('#brand_name_" . $lang['language_id'] ."').val(),";
                            echo "'description_" . $lang['language_id'] . "' : tinyMCE.get('description_". $lang['language_id'] . "').getContent(),";
                        endif;
                    endforeach; 
                ?>
                'brand_status'      : $('#brand_status :selected').val()
                //,'brand_country'      : $('#brand_country :selected').val()
            }),
            dataType: "html",
            async: true,
            beforeSend: function() {
                $('#submit_button').hide();
                $("#processing").show();
            },
            success: function(data){
                parent.$.fancybox.close();
                $("#processing").hide();
                $.prompt('Brand created!',{ show:'slideDown', opacity: 0.5, timeout:2000, overlayspeed:'fast', promptspeed:'fast' });
                $('#list_content').load('<?=sbase_url()?>admin/brands/list_all');
            },
            error: function(xhr,err){
                $("#processing").hide();
                alert("readyState: "+xhr.readyState+"\nstatus: "+xhr.status);
                alert("responseText: "+xhr.responseText);
            }
```

The commented bit is something new being added and that's when I found this issue, I've also copied over the "success" segment just for path comparison. All help appreciated, thanks.

Edited to add the admin section where this is based is https however on localhost the https is crossed out, could this be interfering with the ajax request?

Comment: Just to add I'm working on the locally, this works on the existing live system strangely.

Comment: `<?=sbase_url()?>` is this a typo?

Comment: check chrome's network tab  if the function save_new_brand() has 200 status

Comment: sbase_url() just returns an https prefixed url for secure pages, not a typo. Also checked the network console and everything has a 200 so no issues there. About to try below solution.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use

```
url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>admin/brands/save_new_brand",
```

Comment: Or even better `url: "<?php echo site_url("admin/brands/save_new_brand"); ?>",`

Comment: This doesn't do it I'm afraid, when this is used I get server dialogue boxes popping up upon each request and it breaks the redirect to admin /home. I'll update is I solve it